# Polish citizen wants to move to England with non-EU citizen wife

Tags: united-kingdom, eu-citizens

I'm a Polish citizen and my wife-to-be is Colombian. We've lived in the USA for 3 years (legally, just in case someone asked) and we want to move to UK after we get married. How can my future wife get her work permit in the UK? I've seen a similar question here before but my case seems to be a little different, the question was asked 2 years ago, and laws change. I have never been in the UK, neither has my wife to be. I haven't been to my home country in over three years.

Comment: In what way does your case seem to be a little different?  The facts you've recounted seem very straightforward, but if you have particular concerns that aren't addressed in other questions, we can only address them here if you mention them explicitly.

Comment: Well... First of all that was two years ago. Secondly, neither my wife-to-be or me ever have been in UK

Comment: @Pawel the rules haven't changed in the last 2 years (though they may soon, as you no doubt are aware). Past travel to the UK is not required for you to apply for an EEA family permit.